# Django aggregate Avg vs for loop with prefetch_related()

Tags: python, django, performance, aggregate, prefetch

I have a Review model that is in one to one relationship with Rating model. A user can give a rating according to six different criteria -- cleanliness, communication, check_in, accuracy, location, and value -- which are defined as fields in the Rating model.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    cleanliness     = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    communication   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    check_in        = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    accuracy        = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    location        = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    value           = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Review(models.Model):
    room       = models.ForeignKey('room.Room', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    host       = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='host_reviews')
    guest      = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='guest_reviews')
    rating     = models.OneToOneField('Rating', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content    = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

I am thinking of a way to calculate the overall rating, which would be the average of average of each column in the Rating model. One way could be using Django's aggregate() function, and another option could be prefetching all reviews and looping through each review to manually calculate the overall rating. 
For example,

```
for room in Room.objects.all()
    ratings_dict = Review.objects.filter(room=room)\
            .aggregate(*[Avg(field) for field in ['rating__cleanliness', 'rating__communication', \
               'rating__check_in', 'rating__accuracy', 'rating__location', 'rating__value']])
    ratings_sum = 0
    for key in ratings_dict.keys():
        ratings_sum += ratings_dict[key] if ratings_dict[key] else 0
```

Or, simply looping through,

```
rooms = Room.objects.prefetch_related('review_set')
for room in rooms:
    reviews   = room.review_set.all()
    ratings   = 0
    for review in reviews:
        ratings += (review.rating.cleanliness + review.rating.communication + review.rating.check_in + 
                        review.rating.accuracy + review.rating.location+ review.rating.value)/6
```

Which way would be more efficient in terms of time complexity and result in less DB calls?

Does aggregate(Avg('field_name')) produce one Avg query at the database level per function call?

Will first calling all rooms with prefetch_related() help reduce number of queries later when calling room.review_set.all()?

Comment: Imho the most efficient way would be not to use any iteration at all, but to do a grouped aggregation on an annotated field like `F('cleanliness') + F('communication') + ...`.